# How to get Network data used by running apps Individually in android

Tags: java, android, network-traffic

I want to get network traffic data of each app only which is running in background
after a fixed interval of time.
The code I am using gives the total data transmit & receive from the device.
But I need individual data of each app. please help me to get the data.

My code is:

```
public class TrafficMonitorActivity extends Activity {
TextView latest_rx=null;
TextView latest_tx=null;
TextView previous_rx=null;
TextView previous_tx=null;
TextView delta_rx=null;
TextView delta_tx=null;
TrafficSnapshot latest=null;
TrafficSnapshot previous=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_traffic_monitor);

    latest_rx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.latest_rx);
    latest_tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.latest_tx);
    previous_rx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.previous_rx);
    previous_tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.previous_tx);
    delta_rx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.delta_rx);
    delta_tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.delta_tx);

    takeSnapshot(null);
}

public void takeSnapshot(View v) {
    previous=latest;
    latest=new TrafficSnapshot(this);

    latest_rx.setText(String.valueOf(latest.device.rx));
    latest_tx.setText(String.valueOf(latest.device.tx));

    if (previous!=null) {
        previous_rx.setText(String.valueOf(previous.device.rx));
        previous_tx.setText(String.valueOf(previous.device.tx));

        delta_rx.setText(String.valueOf(latest.device.rx-previous.device.rx));
        delta_tx.setText(String.valueOf(latest.device.tx-previous.device.tx));
    }

    ArrayList<String> log=new ArrayList<String>();
    HashSet<Integer> intersection=new HashSet<Integer>(latest.apps.keySet());

    if (previous!=null) {
        intersection.retainAll(previous.apps.keySet());
    }

    for (Integer uid : intersection) {
        TrafficRecord latest_rec=latest.apps.get(uid);
        TrafficRecord previous_rec=
                    (previous==null ? null : previous.apps.get(uid));

        emitLog(latest_rec.tag, latest_rec, previous_rec, log);
    }

    Collections.sort(log);

    for (String row : log) {
        Log.d("TrafficMonitor", row);
    }
}

private void emitLog(CharSequence name, TrafficRecord latest_rec,
                                            TrafficRecord previous_rec,
                                            ArrayList<String> rows) {
    if (latest_rec.rx>-1 || latest_rec.tx>-1) {
        StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder(name);

        buf.append("=");
        buf.append(String.valueOf(latest_rec.rx));
        buf.append(" received");

        if (previous_rec!=null) {
            buf.append(" (delta=");
            buf.append(String.valueOf(latest_rec.rx-previous_rec.rx));
            buf.append(")");
        }

        buf.append(", ");
        buf.append(String.valueOf(latest_rec.tx));
        buf.append(" sent");

        if (previous_rec!=null) {
            buf.append(" (delta=");
            buf.append(String.valueOf(latest_rec.tx-previous_rec.tx));
            buf.append(")");
        }

        rows.add(buf.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Another class is: TrafficRecord

```
class TrafficRecord {
long tx=0;
long rx=0;
String tag=null;

TrafficRecord() {
    tx=TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();
    rx=TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
}

TrafficRecord(int uid, String tag) {
    tx=TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid);
    rx=TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid);
    this.tag=tag;
}
```

}

TrafficSnapshot:

```
class TrafficSnapshot {
TrafficRecord device=null;
HashMap<Integer, TrafficRecord> apps=
    new HashMap<Integer, TrafficRecord>();

TrafficSnapshot(Context ctxt) {
    device=new TrafficRecord();

    HashMap<Integer, String> appNames=new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    for (ApplicationInfo app :
                ctxt.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(0)) {
        appNames.put(app.uid, app.packageName);
    }

    for (Integer uid : appNames.keySet()) {
        apps.put(uid, new TrafficRecord(uid, appNames.get(uid)));
    }
}
}
```

How can I get individual app data with correspond to app name?

Comment: Try this Tutorial : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-a-network-monitor-using-androids-trafficstats-class/774/

Comment: I also try this one, but that one also gives total data of all applications

Comment: I need individual data used by each app

Comment: Did find any solutions for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is perhaps old thread, but you could use
getUidRxBytes(UID);
getUidTxBytes(UID);

See this link for example:
[How can I check my Android app's network consumption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710484/how-can-i-check-my-android-apps-network-consumption)