# How can I check my Android app's network consumption?

Tags: android, api, network-monitoring

I need to check my Android app's Internet consumption. In my app I have a numerous number of web service APIs being called.

I want to know how much my app consumes the Internet in kB/MB at a full go.

How can I check that? Is there any tool to check that?

Comment: How is such a simple question not a duplicate more than 7 years after Stack Overflow launched?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Actually i already mark as Duplicate but all the questions asked related to get Network Data Usage programatically but in this question OP asked `how to get it by using some Tools?`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Android Studio 2.0** Introduce new `Network` section in `Android Monitor` which can help you with your problem.

[image]

```
Tx == Transmit Bytes Rx == Receive Bytes
```

Comment: I know its an old question, but how to you get the  total used megabytes for a period of time using this tool? The graph only indicates transmission rate at a specific point in time but not the total transmitted so far figure.  I was hoping that i could just mark a section on the graph and get the sum but to no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 11):

There are three ways...

1. You can view in Device/Emulator. Go to **Setting -> Data usage**, and find your application in the list 
   [image]
2. In Eclipse, select **DDMS (perspective) -> Select your package from Devices (left side) -> Click on Network Statistics tab -> Click Start** 
   [image]
3. As already answered, in Android Studio, go to **Android Monitor (bottom tab) -> Network (tab) -> look for Tx (Transmit Data) / Rx (Receive Data)**
   [image]

Answer (score 8):

For view purposes, you can check it in the monitor as mentioned by MD.

To store, you can do that programmatically

```
    int UID = android.os.Process.myUid();
    rxBytes += getUidRxBytes(UID);
    txBytes += getUidTxBytes(UID);
    /**
     * Read UID Rx Bytes
     *
     * @param uid
     * @return rxBytes
     */
    public Long getUidRxBytes(int uid) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        Long rxBytes = 0L;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/uid_stat/" + uid
                    + "/tcp_rcv"));
            rxBytes = Long.parseLong(reader.readLine());
            reader.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            rxBytes = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid);
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rxBytes;
    }

    /**
     * Read UID Tx Bytes
     *
     * @param uid
     * @return txBytes
     */
    public Long getUidTxBytes(int uid) {
        BufferedReader reader;
        Long txBytes = 0L;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/uid_stat/" + uid
                    + "/tcp_snd"));
            txBytes = Long.parseLong(reader.readLine());
            reader.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            txBytes = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid);
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return txBytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice sample, It is helped me lot.

Comment: Not working since Android 6

Answer (score 6):

Have a look: *[Android Monitor](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/help/android-monitor.html)*.

In that there are many topics that you can monitor.

## You will find [Network Monitor](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/help/am-network.html).

**Displaying a Running App in the Network Monitor:**

Follow these steps:

- Connect a hardware device.
- Display Android Monitor.
- Click the Network tab.
- Open an app project and run it on the hardware device.
- To start the Network Monitor, click Pause Pause icon to deselect it.

Any network traffic begins to appear in the Network Monitor:

[image]

The Network Monitor adds up the amount of time it takes for the device to transmit and receive kilobytes of data. The y-axis is in kilobytes per second. The x-axis starts with seconds, and then minutes and seconds, and so on.

- To stop the Network Monitor, click Pause Pause icon again to select it.

Reference: *[Android Monitor](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/tools/help/android-monitor.html)*